# Create Polygons in Python that use the max extents to make a box

Tags: python, shapely, polygon-creation

I have field collected data that is usually collected with 6 points to create a form of polygon. I can subset those 6 points and create the polygon no problem, with this code:

```
eastList = channelFilter['Easting'].tolist()

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(eastList, northList))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:26919'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom]) 
print(polygon.geometry)

polygon.to_file(filename = Polygon_Folder + "\\channelGeom.shp", driver = 'ESRI Shapefile'
```

ChannelFilter is simply the filter of coordinates / points I'm using. However, the order of points collected often goes Bottom middle, Bottom right, bottom left, top middle, top right, top left, meaning the lines cross over each other and give a convex (I think that's the word?) polygon.

Does anyone know a convenient way to take 6 points and create a polygon with those are maximum extents, regardless of the order?